# www::scripter submit_form issue

Tags: perl

I am having trouble with `submit_form` in `WWW::Scripter`. I realize it's really `WWW::Mechanize` that is being called, but it does not work the same. When using the method via `Scripter`, I get a 404 -- Not Found. If I use `Mechanize`, I get a 200. Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Scripter;

my $w = new WWW::Scripter;
$w->get('https://www.lendingclub.com/foliofn/tradingInventory.action');

my $r = $w->submit_form( with_fields => { login_email => 'my@email.com', login_password => 'some_pass' });

print scalar($r->message) . "\n";
```